# How to link a field to a view in OpenERP7?

Tags: forms, odoo, openerp-7

I am modifying a form view in OpenERP7. In the standard form of partners, there is a group of tabs at the bottom. One of them, **Accountancy**, has a couple of fields, **property_account_receivable** and **property_account_payable** which have a link to the account standard form of their corresponding accounts.

That is the behaviour I want to manage for a specific field. This one is **name**, and it is also in the standard form of partners, but inside the **Contacts** tab (this tab only appears if the partner is a company).

Now, if you click on **name**, a popup is opened with some information about the partner. I want to click it and go to the standard form of that partner. I tried changing the line:

```
<a type="open"><field name="name" /></a>
```

But no results, I tried to imitate the code of the account fields and there were some mistakes because they are **fields.property** and name is **fields.char**.

How to manage this?

Answer (score 2):

I think You should do it like this  below

```
  <a name="Field_name" type="object">Here Your Link name</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem a few minutes ago. I had to change the type as you say, object in spite of open, and add also an attribute name="name_of_the_function_which_returns_the_right_view".